# How to share wired internet connection to wifi (non Adhoc)?

Tags: 12.10, network-bridge

I have a wired interconnection in my ubuntu laptop. I want to share this connection to my Nexus 7. I tried creating a Ad-hoc connection but N7 doesn't recognise ad-hoc wifi. So I found my old wireless router ( Beetel 450TC1 ) and connected both my laptop and N7. I ran a web server in my laptop and I am able to see it in N7. Now, How do I forward my wired internet connection to N7? I think I must run some proxy server to forward all requests to eth0 interface. Any ideas, how to set this up?

Comment: If you have setup the router in between the Internet (ADSL or Cable modem) connection and the laptop. Then both the laptop and the N7 should be able to connect to the Internet via the router's WiFi. If this is not the case, please edit the question and explain.

Answer (score 1):

You need some packages and have to configure it:
1. HostAPD
2. DHCP
3. ip masquerading

To know how to configure these packages please read this article: http://techmites.com/laptop-wired-establish-wifi-in-ubuntu/